# How to make a zombie killing detection scoreboard work for a certain gamemode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make it so that when it becomes night, a zombie spawns no matter what at a certain coordinate (which I've managed to do with the simple help of the player having to press a button to change the time to night, and using a chain command block to summon a couple zombies at the same time), and that when the player kills ONE zombie, the scoreboard `LostJournalZombie` goes off, setting the coordinates `1559 52 -1603` to a redstone block, which will then set off another chain of commands, one of which deletes the scoreboard so that the player cannot receive the message twice. I need this to only affect players in adventure mode, so as of now I'm using the command

```
/execute if score @p[gamemode=adventure] LostJournalZombie = 1.. LostJournalZombie run setblock 1559 52 -1603 minecraft:redstone_block.
```

in a repeating command block that is set to always active and unconditional. I've tried changing this to `/execute if score @p[gamemode=adventure] LostJournalZombie = 1 LostJournalZombie run setblock 1559 52 -1603 minecraft:redstone_block` and `/execute if score @p[gamemode=adventure] LostJournalZombie >= 1 LostJournalZombie run setblock 1559 52 -1603 minecraft:redstone_block` and a bunch of others, but none worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the less than(<) and more than(>) symbols don't work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/373160/why-do-the-less-than-and-more-than-symbols-dont-work)

Comment: Again, I've tried using = instead of > and <, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @321Nathango The solution provided in the linked post told you to use `matches`, not to use `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, the command was not showing correctly because apparently without the dots I just added it hides the score part. It is fixed now.

First of all, when I tried the command it says objective names cannot be longer than 16 characters.

Second, @p only checks the nearest player, so the way you have it now, it checks if the nearest player is in adventure mode and has the score.

I am also noticing a syntax error likely causing the issue. The score part checks if the score of one entity equals (or greater/less than etc) the score of another entity. As of now you are checking if a player named "1.."'s LostJournalZombie value is equal to the nearest player's (and only if they are in adventure mode).

A fixed version would be something to the effect of:

/execute as @a[gamemode=adventure] if score @s <.score> = Aceplante <.score> run summon zombie 1559 52 -1603

Since your goal is to summon a zombie though, I added the last part instead of setting a redstone block. Also you will have to replace <.score> with a new scoreboard that is less than 16 characters

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work too well. First of all, I had to change 'if score @s' to 'if score @s LostJournalZombie = 1 LostJournalZombie', but it still didn't work. I've tried experimenting by changing 'as' to 'at' and taking away the gamemode tag, but it still doesn't work. Thank you still, though.

Comment: "At" is only used for fill/setblock/summon etc, things that happen at a location. Effect or data merge would be "as". Also, the way you have it in the previous message would be comparing the score of a player with the name "1", and their score is probably 0 since it does not exist. And in case you didnt notice, I used my name as a placeholder to show you how you need a player name there. You can have any random "name" and it's score. Edit, wait that isnt the right command, some of it must have gotten deleted somehow.